# Identifing a pattern to create a recursive function in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, recursion, numbers

I have been given a sequence of numbers:

```
2, 3, -4, 11, -25, and 62.
```

Taking the changes in these numbers, I am left with

```
1, -7, 15, -36, and 87.
d1 d2  d3  d4       d5

d3 = -2 * d2 + d1
d4 = -2 * d3 + d2 + d1
d5 = -2 * d4 + d3
```

How can I better express this in terms of a recursive Java function that calculates to the nth position?

Comment: what will be the d6 value?
`d6 = -2 * d5 + d4 + d3 ??`

Answer (score 0):

check if it is an odd number starting from 3 if so then it is -2 * the previous 2 numbers
if it is an even number it is the -2 * the previous three numbers

so:
`if n%2 = 1
n = -2 * (n-1) + (n-2);
if n%2 = 0
n = -2 * (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3);`